# Getting <comand line> error - info.plist file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I was using Xcode and tried running the project and suddenly got this error. The info.plist file in build settings is linked to the proper directory. I've tried quitting Xcode and re-starting my computer - no luck. I have no idea what to do. Can't find anything online. Any ideas? Thanks

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to your project file in Xcode, ensure that your path is the path of the info.plist file... Also, make sure the name of the files are the same `../thepathtoyouinfoplist/info.plist` and `info.plist`

[image]

Comment: Try to locate the file in terminal and pwd the directory... Then copy paste in the field

Comment: k so if your not good with terminal, locate your project folder in finder, once you located it open up terminal... then try and follow the path it took you to get to your folder in finder within terminal... For example, you open up finder, go to Documents tab, then Projects, then YourProject. You then locate your info.plist file. Then open terminal, type in `cd Documents/Projects/YourProject`. `cd` means change directory. Then type `ls -al` to list all the files within the directory your currently in. Then to get the path of the directory your in, type `pwd`.

Comment: `/Users/mordechailevi/Desktop/Quotey/Quotey`

Comment: Check out this link, and follow the most upvoted answer... Hopefully it helps. If not, comment back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880184/could-not-read-from-info-plist

Comment: Not at the moment... Im sorry. Really the only thing I can think of is just creating a new project and adding all your files over... Its most likely the worst solution but its a solution.

Comment: But I already have a user base, would this create a brand new app or just be like an update?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean user base? As long your bundle identifiers are the same as well as the app name, you should be good to go. Meaning it should just act like an update. Also make sure your certificates are the same if your app is currently in the stores

Comment: I already have people using the app, didn't know about the bundle identifiers. will try that now. Thanks.

Comment: Just realized I have Core Data in the project - will I have to perform a migrations?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with coredata but you should be fine. From my knowledge core data is just a database stored on the phone. Since everyone's phone has their own database it shouldnt matter. But just for the sake of continuing project development, you shouldn't worry about it. Just create a new project, copy your classes and continue to develop. Then when you find a solution for your info.plist problem, go back and migrate your files back to the original project.